# In Excel, how do you delete line breaks?

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office, macos

In Excel, how do you delete line breaks globally? It's totally messing up my text-to-column I need to do.

Comment: None of these techniques worked for me, for future references. (2016 Macbook, Excel 2018)

Answer (score 5):

**A more Excel way:**

As line-break is CHAR(13), you could try something like this (assuming your text is in A1 and you'll put edited text in B1)

> ```
> B1: =SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(13),"")
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> B1: =SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(13)," ")
> ```

Source: [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2008-macexcel/how-can-i-findreplace-line-breaks-in-mac-2008/fc983c79-7a62-4bdc-8dcc-0b1da2d80bb1)

Comment: line break is char(10) not 13

Answer (score 3):

## Q: In Excel, how do you delete line breaks globally?

A: No, Mac's `Find & Replace` doen't work.

I will walk you thru my version of a fix.

There are [lots of website discussions](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&lr=lang_en&newwindow=1&hl=en&as_qdr=all&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&ei=Y0ZaXOY6pp_SAtOGrqAJ&q=replace%20%22carriage%20return%22%20OR%20%22line%20break%22%20OR%20%22newline%22%20%22excel%22%20%22mac%22&oq=replace%20%22carriage%20return%22%20OR%20%22line%20break%22%20OR%20%22newline%22%20%22excel%22%20%22mac%22), but, there doesn't seem to be any resolution,

Using **just** the `Find & Replace`.

### Example from:

[image: My Version Of Excel]

1. Open your Excel file
2. Highlight all cells

   1. [image]
   2. Select the top left corner **Above** `Row 1` & **Left of** `Column A`
   3. Or Select a cell and do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> at least twice
3. `Auto Format` the Column Heights by <kbd>Double Left Clicking</kbd> inbetween `row 1 & 2` (any row will work)

   1. Also, Make sure to take off the <kbd>Wrap Text</kbd> as well; As this can be misleading if it is on.
4. Should change appearance from this:

   1. [image]
      To this: [image]
5. Create a New column to the right of the column
6. Then Type in this formula `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(13),""),CHAR(10)," - "))`
7. Press Enter

   1. You should now see your cell formatted cleanly
   2. Highlight the newly formatted cell
   3. <kbd>Double Left Click</kbd> on the Bottom Right Hand of the Cell to format the whole column with the formula. [image: Click the Bottom Right Box on the corner]
8. Now Highlight the entire new column with the formula

   1. Right Click and <kbd>Copy</kbd> this column
   2. Then Right Click on the original column

      1. Select <kbd>Paste Special</kbd>
      2. [image: Right Click for the Paste Special]
   3. Select <kbd>Values</kbd> radio button & Click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>

      1. [image: Paste Special Options]
   4. Make sure to <kbd>Delete</kbd> the created columns with the formula.

That should at least be a simple workaround.

Your end result should allow you to resize your column heights again down to the 16px default column height.
[image: Final Result.]

Formula Reference: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/03/remove-carriage-returns-excel/

> Note: The Manual Find and replace in native Excel doesn't work using [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-for-mac-acf5419e-1f87-444d-962f-4e951a658ccd)

Answer (score 2):

A simple technique which also works in Mac versions of Excel is to use the formula "clean". This removes all non-printing characters including line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest Way to Remove all line breaks.

Copy the target column containing all the line breaks in to blank Word document (Works for rows and entire tables)

In Word
**<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for Mac) - To Find and Replace**

**Enter `^p` in the find field**

> "`^p`" is the character symbol for line paragraph/break

Key Combo <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> Then <kbd>p</kbd>

**Enter desired character in replace field** (Likely one space)

**Click replace all.**

**Done - Copy column from word back into excel.**

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue for years and could not find the line break equivalent in Mac Excel, and now what I do is:

1.I insert an empty column next to the column with line break issue then add the following command `=clean(Cell number)` 
*cell number will be the first row of the column with line break issue.

2.Then grab the bottom right corner and drag the function through all rows.

3.When finished dragging, copy the new column data and special paste it with values only in a new column, the new column is guaranteed to be without line breaks as the clean function gets read of all issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple, non-Excel way to get rid of all the line breaks in your text:

Paste the data into TextEdit, put your cursor at the end of any line, then hold `shift` and press the right arrow once. This will select the invisible new line character. Now hit `command + c` to copy this invisible character, and then got to

```
Edit > Find > Find and Replace...
```

and search for your copied character and replace it everywhere with just a `space`.

Now you shouldn't have any more line breaks in your text. :)

(On a side note, you don't need to replace with a `space` you can replace it with another symbol if that may be more convenient for what you're doing in Excel.)

Answer (score 0):

If there are only a few of them, select the cell, then click in the formula box.  This makes the formula box act like a text field, so the arrow keys and delete and other editing functions will work.  If there are many, use the replace method other posted.